# Animation in xaml doesn't work, but in code works

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, eventtrigger

I have a quite tricky problem with my `Animation` in simple WPF application.
I have a custom `Panel` with X and Y attached `DependencyProperty` which give information how to arrange the layout. I have a `CustomControl` called `MovableGameCharacter` and I want to animate the movement on the panel.
So here is the code:
**In xaml:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MovableGameCharacter}" BasedOn="{StaticResource gamecharacter}" x:Key="movablegamecharacter">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MovableGameCharacter}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MoveRight">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:GameBoardPanel.X)" To="100" From="10"
                                     Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and my `MovableGameCharacter` in code just raises one of the `RoutedEvent` associated with move.

```
public void Move(Direction d)
    {
        switch (d)
        {
            case Direction.Left:
                RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MoveLeftEvent, this));
                break;
            case Direction.Up:
                RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MoveUpEvent, this));
                break;
            case Direction.Right:
                RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MoveRightEvent, this));
                break;
            case Direction.Down:
                RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MoveDownEvent, this));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

And the events are defined as follows (for example MoveRightEvent):

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent MoveRightEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("MoveRight", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(MovementEventHandler), typeof(MovableGameCharacter));
```

However, I am very surprised that this works (added in constructor):

```
MoveRight += (x, e) => { BeginAnimation(GameBoardPanel.XProperty, new DoubleAnimation(100, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)))); };
```

So I probably went wrong in xaml, but I don't know what I did wrong. I have read that I have to write

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:GameBoardPanel.X)"
```

for attached properties, but it still does not work.

Comment: Your TargetProperty will just be `X` as you're targeting a set property of `TranslateTransform` which you also need to declare on that panel as a `RenderTransform` then the `TranslateTransform` will need a `x:Name` that will go in your animation as the `TargetName`. Share your panel xaml we'll get ya sorted.

Comment: should not be instad of "(local:GameBoardPanel.X)" "{local:GameBoardPanel.X}"?

Comment: @Gusman no it shouldn't, because it is not a `MarkupExtension`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, i'm accostumed to use XAML only on Xamarin and everything goes with brakets, I then assume it's because thy implemented all as extensions.